# Unable to scrape amazon orders page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I currently making a project which will get all the orders i've ordered on amazon and categorize them and then write them to an excel file. The problem is, when i try to scrape the page using `bs4`, i get the result as `None`.

I've made a similar project before, which will search amazon for the product you want to search for then save all the data about that product like `name`, `price`, `review` in a json file.
That worked perfectly.

But this doesnt seem to work

here is the code -

```
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
}

link = 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/your-account/order-history?opt=ab&digitalOrders=1&unifiedOrders=1&returnTo=&orderFilter=year-2020'

data = requests.get(link, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

product = soup.find('div', class_="a-box-group a-spacing-base order")

print(product)
```

I'm a beginner, but I think its because I need to log in to get my details, but my password is already saved in my browser.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think that Amazon will just let everyone scrape any page without authentication. 

I believe there is an official API for those cases

Comment: You can't expect the credentials stored in your browser to be used when you are running a python script. You need to use something like selenium for that, even then if 2-FA is enabled, it will be very difficult to work.

Answer (score -1):

See [this](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-python) GitHub project for reference

Amazon, like most prominent companies, doesn't allow simple **scraping** and needs some form of auth.

Comment: thanks, but it looks like its made for sellers not customers, are you sure about this? Did you use it before?